# Ребят помогите с реализацией идеи

Tags: outlook, zoom

Есть веб интерфейс GLIP (https://glpi-project.org/) работает как helpdesk.
Есть программа ZOOM (https://zoom.us/) для конференций.
Я простой эникейщик с маленьким опытом!

---

Идея в чем, хотелось бы при подачи заявки на конференцию, заявителем, создавалась ссылка на ZOOM(приглашения на конференцию).

---

Пример:
Заявитель отправляет запрос на адрес тех.поддержки через Outlook. (1)Тема:"ZOOM Совещание..." в письме перечисляет список контактов из Outlook, в ответ на ее сообщение приходит автоматически ссылка на ZOOM конференцию, где он(она) руководитель, а остальным ссылка с приглашением. И при добавлении в тему(1) зума идет форма к заполнению, при нарушении которого письмо не отправиться.

---

Посоветуйте что почитать, к кому обратиться, что посмотреть да-бы реализовать данную идею!
p.s GLIP работает с Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Если вы действительно хотите использовать GLPI в данных целях (хотя я слабо представляю смысл этой затеи, если только чтобы все запросы на создание встречи в ZOOM проходили через helpdesk).

Я вижу только такой путь:

1. Для начала, в транспортных правилах вашего почтового сервера выставить запрет на отправку писем если поле кому стоит ящик вашего GLPI, чтобы не было копирования заявок (иначе будут попытки создать копию встречи).
2. Далее написать плагин для GLPI (`$PLUGIN_HOOKS['item_add']` вам в помощь, плюс [документация](https://glpi-developer-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/master/plugins/hooks.html#standards-hooks)), который будет реагировать на ваше сообщение, парсить из нее данные о встрече, и делать POST запрос к [API Zoom](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/meetings/meetingcreate).
3. По результату отправлять письмо, либо инициатору с отказом, либо тем кто находится в наблюдателях со ссылкой.

**НО!**

Учитывая особенность GLPI объединять заявки по теме письма, вам надо еще придумать, чтобы тема в каждой встрече отличалась от других таких же заявок.

Иначе все будет сыпаться в одну заявку, что совсем не хорошо.

Если возникнут проблемы в реализации, можно понадеяться на помощь в этих местах:

- https://t.me/glpi_ru
- https://t.me/glpien
- Либо я, чем смогу, тем помогу.

---

Насколько мне известно, Outlook и GLPI между собой никак не взаимодействуют, можно хоть thunderbird использовать суть не изменится.